# jquery fadeIn function with as callback function with $("this") parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a simple function so an element will fade in and then will fade out. 
This is my code:

```js
function ShowBoxes() {
    $("#divTestArea21").fadeIn("fast", function () {
        FadeThisOut($(this));
    });
    $("#divTestArea22").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#divTestArea23").fadeIn(2000);
}


function FadeThisOut(sender) {
    sender.fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery test</title>
    <script  src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/IndexScript.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/SiteStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />


 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divTestArea21" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none; background-color: #89BC38;"></div>
    <div id="divTestArea22" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none; background-color: #C3D1DF;"></div>
    <div id="divTestArea23" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none; background-color: #9966FF;"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowBoxes();">Show boxes</a>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain to me why it isn't working and how to fix it?

Edit: you are right, I had a paramater for FadeThisOut function  , but I played with my code for a bit and tried other things so I forgat to bring it back. Anyway, I removed the double-quotes and now it's working. Thanks all.

Comment: Where is `sender` defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you call your function with $(this) as parameter but you declare it without, start by putting it this way :

```
function FadeThisOut(object) {
}
```

Secondly you use sender[0], but you don't show us what is sender array.

Thirdly in your function call, you should call the current object without quotes, ie: $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use

```
FadeThisOut($(this));
```

(without the double-quotes)

As Vincent said, you also have no argument to the FadeThisOut function